# Updating the same variable between two activities and the UIs in both activities' RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I have two activities which share an exact same list, `ListA`, that has a property called `amount`.

In my first activity, I have:

- A `RecyclerView` with `ViewHolder`s. Inside each of this `ViewHolder`, I have a button to manipulate the `amount` of an item in `ListA` (each `ViewHolder` has an item inside `ListA` which is associated with it). This `RecyclerView` has two types of `ViewHolder`: `Header` and `Item`. The `Item` `ViewHolder` shows the `amount` of the item inside `ListA` it is associated with.
- A `Button` to go to the second activity

In my second activity, I have:

- The list from first activity (`ListA`) copy (passed using `Intent` and `Parcelable`)
- A `RecyclerView` that is basically the same (information-wise) as the one in first activity with added functionalities. One of the functionalities includes manipulating the `amount` of an item in `ListA`. However, this `RecyclerView` only has one `ViewHolder` type (without `Header`). Also, there are some extra layouts that are present in the `Item` `ViewHolder` (because of the added functionalities).
- A `Button` to return to the first activity

I want to:

- Pass `ListA` from first activity to second activity and vice-versa
- Update UI in first activity's `RecyclerView`'s `ViewHolders` when second activity manipulates `ListA` and goes back to first activity; and vice-versa

What is the best way to do this? Currently, I'm passing `ListA` as a `Parcelable Intent` to second activity. However, I found it hard to update the UI accordingly on my first activity's `RecyclerView`s `Item ViewHolder`. This is because the callback passed to update its `Item ViewHolder`'s UI requires the specified id of the layout that represents `amount` is triggered by the button press (in `onBindViewHolder`), which I am not pressing when I'm returning to the first activity.

Comment: My first idea related to this, would be to have second list inside a fragment (and using a public method in your activity which you'll pass the updated data to the first `RecyclerView` and notify it) 

The second idea, would be to handle onBackPressed in second activity, store the data to be updated, and update UI in first one in onResume. 

Now, neither of these two seems `"elegant"` enough :) 
So, in the end, I'd probably going to use https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Room with live data resolve your problem. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata If you don't wanna use internal database you could try use 2 Fragments in one Activity instead of 2 Activity and manage data in the activity(or it's presenter, viewmodel ect...)